# Combine these regex expressions

Tags: ios, regex

I have two regular expressions: `^(\\p{L}|[0-9]|_)+$` and `#[^[:punct:][:space:]]+` (the first is used in Java, the second on iOS). I want to combine these into one expression, to match either one or the other in iOS.
The first one is for a username so I also need to add a `@` character to the start of that one. What would that look like?

Comment: do you mean just throw a pipe between them?  (^(\\p{L}|[0-9]|_)+$)|(#[^[:punct:][:space:]]+)

Comment: I did think to do that but I'm not sure if that dollar sign works in iOS, I'm not good at regex within iOS. Also where would the `@` sign go? before the `^`?

Comment: ^ means the beginning of the line so @ would go to the right of that.  $ should be fine in iOS.  Give it a shot if it works I'll write up a full answer :)

Comment: I think I solved it using `@(\\p{L}|[0-9]|_)+|#[^[:punct:][:space:]]+` without the ^ and $. It's to detect these patterns within a long string so doesn't necessarily need to be at the beginning and end.

Comment: You may use `[@#]\\w+` because in iOS the ICU regex library is used and all shorthand character classes are Unicode aware. Note that `[^[:punct:][:space:]]+` = `[[:alnum:]]` which is almost the same as `\w`, just the latter also matches an underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^(\\p{L}|[0-9]|_)+$` pattern in Java matches the same way as in ICU library used in iOS (they are very similar): a whole string consisting of 1 or more Unicode letters, ASCII digits or `_`. It is poorly written as the alternation group is quantified and that is much less efficient than a character class based solution, `^[\\p{L}0-9_]+$`.

The `#[^[:punct:][:space:]]+` pattern matches a `#` followed with 1 or more chars other than punctuation/symbols and whitespace chars (that is, 1 or more letters or digits, or alphanumeric chars).

What you seek can be writtern as

```
@[\\p{L}0-9_]+|[^[:punct:][:space:]]+
```

or

```
@[\\p{L}0-9_]+|#[[:alnum:]]+
```

or if you want to limit to ASCII digits and not match Unicode digits:

```
@[\\p{L}0-9_]+|#[\\p{L}0-9]+
```

It matches

- `@` - a `@` symbol
- `[\\p{L}0-9_]+` - 1 or more Unicode letters, ASCII diigts, `_`
- `|` - or
- `#` - a `#` char
- `[[:alnum:]]+` - 1 or more letters or digits.
- `[^[:punct:][:space:]]+` - any 1+ chars other than punctuation/symbols and whitespace.

Basically, all these expressions [match strings like this](https://regex101.com/r/8XPgBC/1).

If you want to match `#SomeThing_123` in full, just use `[@#]\\w+`, a `@` or `#` and then 1 or more letters, digits or `_`, or to only allow ASCII digits, `[@#][\\p{L}0-9_]+`.

A word boundary may be required at the end of the pattern, `[@#][\\p{L}0-9_]+\\b`.

Comment: This is very in depth, thank you! The one that works for me is `@[\p{L}0-9_]+|#[^[:punct:][:space:]]+` as I need to use special characters like ı and ö, but no `_` in the hashtag one.

Comment: @Tometoyou If you found my answer helpful please also consider upvoting it.